# Write JavaFX Blob data field image

Tags: javafx, blob, filechooser

In my class, the attribute where the image will be saved is defined like this:

```
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "NOTA_FISCAL", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "mediumblob")
    public byte[] getNOTA_FISCAL() {
        return NOTA_FISCAL;
    }

    public void setNOTA_FISCAL(byte[] NOTA_FISCAL) {
        this.NOTA_FISCAL = NOTA_FISCAL;
    }
```

In a project I made using Swing, I used JFileChooser to read an image from my computer to later insert it into the database, we can see that the file is converted to Bytes before inserting the item.

```
private void selecionarNF(ActionEvent event) {
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        int res = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File arquivo = fc.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("Arquivo: " + arquivo + "");
            textCaminhoNF.setText(String.valueOf(arquivo));
            try {
                byte[] fotonf = new byte[(int) arquivo.length()];
                FileInputStream fileInputfotonf = new FileInputStream(arquivo);
                fileInputfotonf.read(fotonf);
                fileInputfotonf.close();
                fotoNF = fotonf;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // System.out.println(ex.printStackTrace().toString());
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Você nao selecionou nenhum arquivo.");
        }
```

I'm implementing it with JavaFX, I could even continue using Swing, but I intend to use the Windows file explorer, this way using FileChooser, however I'm having problems capturing the image and passing it to an object of type File, the . getSelectedFile() doesn't exist for FileChooser, I searched a lot on the internet and couldn't find a way to capture this file. What would be the correct way?

```
        Stage s = new Stage();        
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();        
        textCaminhoNF.setText(fc.showOpenDialog(s).getAbsolutePath());       
        
        File arquivo = fc.getSelectedFile(); //his line shows the error, because there is no .getSelectItem
        
        if (fc != null) {            
            System.out.println("No is null");    
            try
            {
                byte[] fotonf = new byte[(int) fc.length()];
                FileInputStream fileInputfotonf = new FileInputStream(fc);
                fileInputfotonf.read(fotonf);
                fileInputfotonf.close();
                fotoNF = fotonf;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // System.out.println(ex.printStackTrace().toString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have `textCaminhoNF.setText(fc.showOpenDialog(s).getAbsolutePath());`. That's setting the text (of a label?) to the selected file's path. That means you have gotten the file. The problem is you don't store it in a variable, so you lose all references to it. There is no property of `FileChooser` that lets you get the previously selected file. You'll have to do something like `File file = fc.showOpenDialog(s);` and then use `file` as needed (checking that it's not `null`, which your current code does not do; i.e., the `textCaminhoNF.setText(...)` line is vulnerable to an NPE).

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what @slaw has mentioned. You are not saving the file reference returned from showOpenDialog.

Below is a quick demo [from my archives ;-) ] when I tried to check the behavior of FileChooser:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ChooseImage_Demo extends Application {

    ImageView myImageView;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button button = new Button("Search for Image");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            try {
                BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
                Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
                myImageView.setImage(image);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        myImageView = new ImageView();
        myImageView.setFitWidth(500);
        myImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        VBox vBox = new VBox(10);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(button, myImageView);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 800, 800);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Image Chooser");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to read the file into a buffered image and convert it into an FXImage.  A JavaFX Image constructor can read the file directly once it is converted to a URL or stream (assuming the image is stored in a compatible format).

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for tip :). Yeah the following code is working `Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());` Did'nt noticed this constructor.

Comment: java naming conventions please;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I did it this way and it worked, it's writing correctly to the database too.

```
@FXML
private void selecionarNF(ActionEvent event) {

    ImageView myImageView = null;
    myImageView = new ImageView();
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    try {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
        Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
        myImageView.setImage(image);
        imageToByte(String.valueOf(file));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    textCaminhoNF.setText(String.valueOf(file));
}
```